# Does "assesse" have a particular meaning in information security?

Tags: terminology

From [this job description](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/143282/human-factors-researcher-human-centered-design-mit-lincoln-laboratory), bold added:

> The human factors expert is needed to conduct research on human subjects that perform tasks for full spectrum cyber operations.  The researcher will define, develop and conduct studies and instrumented experimentation of human subjects and teams to define or improve operational workflows as well as **perform assesse** and perform solutions analysis of capabilities for cyber operations.

Does "assesse" have a particular meaning in this context?

"Assessments" seems unlikely because then the word "perform" after the following "and" would be redundant.  "Assess" seems unlikely because then the *preceding* "perform" would be very out of place.

Is this a technical term I'm not familiar with, or is it like "covfefe?"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a typo. Either way the job description has a quite buzzwordy feel to it.

Comment: I'm guessing it was meant to be "assessments".

Comment: I read and re-read the job announcement and have no idea of what they are looking for. I agree with @MikeOunsworth that this is certainly "assessments" (which will be performed, and then solutions analysis will be performed too :))